# Run IIS and jboss/glassfish/wildfly on a single VPS

Tags: java, iis, glassfish, vps, wildfly

I was wondering if anyone knows of any solutions to run IIS and a java server side by side. Ideally what I'd love to do is not to be required to do ".com" and ".com:8080" for the two separate servers. What I'd really love is for something like dotnet.mysite.com to direct/route to an IIS server and java.mysite.com to direct/route to wildfly.

Does such a solution exist? or will multiple port numbers be required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) to configure IIS to connect to tomcat on port 8080 on the server machine. Then IIS will act as a [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) and will forward appropriately configured paths to the wildfly instance. And yes, you can set-up routes based on the host header.

Comment: This has been insightful so far. However I'm not quite sure how to set this up, do you have any links to good documentation or tutorials how to do so?

Comment: @Benji I get lots of good links when I google ARR IIS tomcat. For example, [How to configre ARR as reverse proxy for tomcat?](http://forums.iis.net/t/1154978.aspx?How+to+configre+ARR+as+reverse+proxy+for+tomcat+). It's a really easy UI and includes some advanced [rewriting capability](http://forums.iis.net/t/1169769.aspx) (matching hostnames is a trivial rule to define).

Comment: Thanks Elliot. I was confused a bit at first. I was trying to do the entire ARR setup (server farms et all). I finally realized I just needed to turn on enable proxy, then do URL Rewrites to where I need to go. I dont know if thats what you intened me to learn or try, but thats what I got to work :)